# How do I access a user's friend's email Ids using OAuth 2?

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I am unable to access the user's friends email Id. I get their first and last name, pic_square but their email and contact_email are always null. The [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) I am using is:

```
select uid, first_name, last_name, name, pic_big, email, contact_email from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())
```

What is the solution?

Comment: You probably don't get them for a good reason. The email of a user who has not authenticated with you is should never be given out to anyone..

Comment: What exactly you mean by authenticating with me? I thought it to be this way, My friends have made their email Id "public" (visible to all). And if i login from my account and allow the app to access my friend's data(like their name, email and all), i should get it..

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

permission: email

Provides access to the user's primary email address in the email property. Do not spam users. Your use of email must comply both with Facebook policies and with the CAN-SPAM Act.

Then for accessing a friend's email, the documentation says there is no way to access it using the API.

However, you should check accessing the graph `https://graph.facebook.com/{friendUserId}`  and see if the public email is listed.  However, I'm nor sure this will work.